# SQL Server : PRECEDING with another condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is working fine: The query is to find the sum & Avg for the last 3 months and last year. It is working fine, till I got a new request to break the query down to more details by `AwardCode`.

So how to include that?

I mean for this section

```
SUM(1.0 * InvolTerm) OVER (ORDER BY Calendar_Date ASC 
                           ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS  InvolMov3Mth,
```

I want to find the last 3 months based on `AwardCode`.

My original query that is working is

```
SELECT 
    Calendar_Date, Mth,  NoOfEmp, MaleCount, FemaleCount,
    SUM(1.0*InvolTerm) OVER (ORDER BY Calendar_Date ASC 
                             ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS  InvolMov3Mth,
    SUM(1.0*TotalTerm) OVER (ORDER BY Calendar_Date ASC 
                             ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS TermSum12Mth 
FROM @X
```

The result is

[image]

But now I need to add another group AwardCode

```
SELECT 
    Mth,  AwardCode, NoOfEmp, MaleCount, FemaleCount,
    SUM(1.0 * InvolTerm) OVER (ORDER BY Calendar_Date ASC 
                               ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS  InvolMov3Mth,
    SUM(1.0 * TotalTerm) OVER (ORDER BY Calendar_Date ASC 
                               ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS TermSum12Mth 
FROM @X
```

The result will be like this

[image]

You can notice that the sum of InvolMov3Mth & TermSum12Mth for the whole period does not match the query above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer for my question.

I used PARTITION BY AwardCode before ORDER BY

seems to be working.

```
SUM(1.0*TotalTerm) OVER (PARTITION BY AwardCode ORDER BY Calendar_Date ASC 
                        ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS TermSum12Mth,
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. "Partition by" will make it work for your requirment